# Javascript: sort multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array

After creating a multi-dim array like this, how do I sort it?

Assuming 'markers' is already defined:

```
var location = [];
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  location[i] = {};
  location[i]["distance"] = "5";
  location[i]["name"] = "foo";
  location[i]["detail"] = "something";
}
```

For the above example, I need to sort it by 'distance'.
I've seen other questions on sorting arrays and multi-dim arrays, but none seem to work for this.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
location.sort(function(a,b) {

  // assuming distance is always a valid integer
  return parseInt(a.distance,10) - parseInt(b.distance,10);

});
```

javascript's `array.sort` method has an optional parameter, which is a function reference for a custom compare. the return values are `>0` meaning `b` first, `0` meaning `a` and `b` are equal, and `<0` meaning `a` first.

Comment: This worked, although "distance" was a decimal (like "964.543") so parseInt had to be removed, otherwise the sorting wasn't accurate past the decimal point.

Comment: @Deca `parseFloat(a.distance)` would be proper in that case.

Comment: Works like a frickin' charm! So simple, but perfect.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried this?

```
location.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.distance - b.distance;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Both sort functions posted so far should work, but your main problem is going to be using `location` as a variable as it is already system defined.

Comment: +1 good point. But it isn't really an answer... :) You should've commented  on one of them.