# Sort multidimensional array by the 5th field

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array of array (2 dimensions):

```
var myArray = [
    ["DVD Title 1","label1","releasedate2","details1", 5241.2541],
    ["DVD Title 1","label3","releasedate1","details1", 8452.654],
    ["DVD Title 1","label3","releasedate2","details1", 45465.5465],
    ["DVD Title 1","label2","releasedate1","details1", 451.545],
    ["DVD Title 1","label1","releasedate1","details1", 7458.6545],
    ["DVD Title 2","label2","releasedaten","detailsn", 4545.545],
    ["DVD Title 2","label1","releasedaten","detailsn", 545.545]
];
```

I want to sort this array, order by ascending, by the 5th field (the float number).

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you even search for this, it has been answered here before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: sort multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886165/javascript-sort-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 8):

```
myArray.sort(function(a,b){
    return a[4] - b[4];
});
```

Comment: Crap, should have refreshed before I posted.