# sort multidimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I would like to sort a multidimensional array of doubles.

The array looks like this : [[1,2],[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]]

I would like to sort it by the X value, and keep the x,y values paired.

I searched the site for multidimentional sorting and found threads like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886165/javascript-sort-multidimensional-array) where the sort function is modified like so:

```
location.sort(function(a,b) {

  // assuming distance is always a valid integer
  return parseInt(a.distance,10) - parseInt(b.distance,10);

});
```

I'm not sure how to modify this function to work for me, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just compare the array values -

```
var myarray =  [[1,2],[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]];

myarray.sort(function(a,b) { return a[0] - b[0]; });
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that was pretty obvious!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to compare the parts of `a` and `b` that you want to. With numbers you can use their difference:

```
location.sort(function(a, b){
    return a[0] - b[0];
});
```

Note that the array you provided already is sorted by the first value in each array. If you want to sort in descending order instead you can do this:

```
location.sort(function(a, b){
    return b[0] - a[0];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The safest way of achieving this is to do what you have in your question, but with numeric keys:

```
location.sort(function(a,b) { return a[0]-b[0]; })
```

If by some chance the **first element of each child array is always a single digit**:

```
location.sort(); 
//only works if first element in child arrays are single digit (0-9)
//as in the example: [[1,2],[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]]
//[[1,2],[22,3],[5,6],[8,9]] - will not work as 22 is not a single digit
```

Comment: Maybe useful as a comment, but this answer is going to confuse somebody.

Comment: @Mathletics It's an answer - if the first element (x) is a single digit `location.sort()` works. How is that not a solution?

Comment: Some noob is going to read that, miss the part about single digits (not understanding that sort, by default, is a string compare, which is why that works), and end up asking another question that could be easily answered by reading [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: @Mathletics I've tried to make it more obvious - however I feel it's worth keeping there as it is much simpler to read and less code to manage (when possible to safely use)